# Android Audio Recording

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-audiorecord

I'm trying to develop android app that need user voice recording. i see many code but nothing work with me.it open but it didn't record anything.

here is the code:

```
package com.example.record8;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaRecorder recorder;
File audiofile = null;
private static final String TAG = "SoundRecordingActivity";
private View startButton;
private View stopButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startButton = findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    stopButton = findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
}

public void startRecording(View view) throws IOException {

    startButton.setEnabled(false);
    stopButton.setEnabled(true);

    File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try {
        audiofile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", sampleDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "sdcard access error");
        return;
    }
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
}

public void stopRecording(View view) {
    startButton.setEnabled(true);
    stopButton.setEnabled(false);
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
}

protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
 }
```

here is the xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:text="@string/startrecording" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:text="@string/stoprecording" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFormat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnStop"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:text="@string/audio_format" />
```

i don't know why it dosen't record.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link,

http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/06/voice-recording-in-android.html

I too have implemented audio recording from this blog and it's completely working fine for you also.

and also make sure you have this below 2 permission in android manifest file while implementing this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

also you can download the source code by visiting this below link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhcswyht20xhud2/Android%20Audio%20Recording.zip

Hope this will help you.